# How to copy fish config files to remote computer?

Tags: fish

I am looking for instructions or a script to copy my fish config files to a new computer via scp. Or at least build a tar file with all of them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note we're not a script or code-writing service. We can help if you [edit] your question to indicate what you've tried (including any attempted scripts, etc.) and specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you use multiple computers regularly, you'll find putting your config files in git greatly helps keep your various machines in sync.

Answer (score 1):

All your fish config files are in *~/.config/fish* or a subdirectory of that directory. So all you need to do is `scp -pr ~/.config/fish remote_host:`. Or `tar cf fish_cfg.tar .config/fish`.

Comment: that was my first thought. After copying configs like this I see that for instance, the command prompt looks different.

Comment: one problem is I see is that there is file `fishd.paco` where paco is my current computer name. Obviously the name of other computer is different. Another problem is that I am using OMG which casues error `source: Error encountered while sourcing file “/home/lord/.local/share/omf/init.fish”`

Comment: The `fishd.paco` file contains universal vars. Which, for most users, is just the vars that define the color theme. In fish 3.0 the name no longer includes the hostname or ethernet address. If you can't upgrade just capture the output of `set -u` on the source system. Then `set -u` those vars on the destination system. I don't use third-party plugin managers like OMF. But, obviously, all you need to do is copy *~/.local/share/omf*.